# Calculating relative error in subtracting two approximate numbers

Tags: numerical-methods, self-learning, error-propagation

My numerical analysis textbook says:

Let $u=x_1+x_2$

Then, absolute error in $u$ is $\Delta u= \Delta x_1+ \Delta x_2$

Relative error in $u$ is $\frac{\Delta u}{u}=\frac{\Delta x_1+ \Delta x_2}{x_1+x_2}$

When $u=x_1 - x_2$, then absolute error $\Delta u$  is same as that in addition, i.e., $\Delta x_1+ \Delta x_2$.
But while calculating relative error, separately $\frac{\Delta x_1}{x_1}$ and $\frac{\Delta x_2}{x_2}$ are calculated, and then relative error in $u$ is said to be $\frac{\Delta x_1}{x_1} - \frac{\Delta x_2}{x_2}$.

I cannot understand why the relative error in subtraction is not $\frac{\Delta u}{u} = \frac{\Delta x_1+ \Delta x_2}{x_1-x_2}$.

Please anyone help me clear this doubt. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. You should definitely be scaling against the target quantity.

Comment: (That said, the issues about signs should be noted here, if $\Delta x_i$ are signed. When they both happen to have the same sign, the relative error of subtraction is smaller than $\frac{|\Delta x_1|+|\Delta x_2|}{x_1-x_2}$. Sometimes people try to deal with this possibility, in particular the "physicist error propagation" technique often taught in first semester physics classes takes this effect into account...but that technique has its own issues, and in fact this case is one where it performs quite badly.)

Answer (score 1):

The result proposed in the textbook is just wrong. I would be very cautious about using a textbook containing such a basic mistake. The relative error in a subtraction is not the subtraction of the relative errors. Using Taylor's formula applied to $f(x,y)=x-y$ you get that, as a first order approximation,

$$
\frac{\Delta f}{f} \approx x \frac{f'_x(x,y)}{f(x,y)} \frac{\Delta x}{x} + y \frac{f'_y(x,y)}{f(x,y)} \frac{\Delta y}{y} = \frac{x}{x-y} \frac{\Delta x}{x} - \frac{y}{x-y} \frac{\Delta y}{y}
$$

Here you can see the potential problem of large   errors when subtracting two close quantities. This problem is known as "subtractive cancelling".